# Will dbCommand.Close() close the connection as well?

Tags: asp.net, ado.net

I have the following ado.net code, if I already use **using** to wrap my DBCommand, do I have to close the underneath connection explicitly?

Thanks,

```
       public static void ExecuteSQL(int Id)
        {
            Database db;
            const string sqlCommand = "Stored Procedure Name";
            try
            {
                db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();
                using (DbCommand dbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand(sqlCommand))
                {
                    db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "p_Id", DbType.Int32, Id);
                    db.ExecuteNonQuery(dbCommand);
**//do I have to close connection explicitely here??**
                    if (dbCommand.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
                    {
                        dbCommand.Connection.Close();
                    }
                    dbCommand.Connection.Dispose();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.Log.Error(ex.StackTrace, ex);
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, if all you have wrapped in the `using` block is the `DbCommand`, then you *will* have to explicitly close the `DbConnection`, as you currently do in your code. It is sufficient, however, simply to call `Dispose`. You do not need to call both `Close` and `Dispose`.

Comment: I believe @Satya is correct in this case and your answer is actually incorrect.

Comment: @CodeBlend: In the case where someone is using Enterprise Library, then yes, her answer is correct. However, while the code does reference classes like `Database`, the content of the question and the tags don't reference EntLib. As a result, if people are searching for an answer to the question as it's been asked, then this would still be correct.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.willydev.net/descargas/WillyDev_EntLib_TestGuide.pdf

The application block closes the database connections after it is finished with them. For example, the implementation of the ExecuteNonQuery method includes a using statement. The using statement obtains resources, executes a statement, and disposes of the resources. In this case, the resource is the database connection. In the case of the ExecuteReader method, the application block uses the Command-Behavior.CloseConnection method to close the connection after the reader closes.

Comment: So the response marked as 'the answer' here is completely wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This post is old, but I'm answering to say I'm sure the connection is closed if we're using this block with EnterpriseLibrary (the classes and method names in the code block makes me think about this).
The guy who made the question, and who answered should explicitly consider if we are talking about EnterbriseLibrary or not.
I tested with a finally block, and YES, the connection is closed automatically after the using block with DbCommand.

Comment: Can you post the code, I would like an example to prove that what you are saying is correct although I think it is

Answer (score -1):

No, you do not.

Once the end of the using block is hit, dispose is called for you.

Comment: I have no idea why this is being upvoted, as it's just plain wrong. You absolutely have to close the connection. This question is about having to dispose the **connection**, not the **command**. "using" the command alone does not do so.

Comment: Based on the comment in his code and the fact that he is explicitly calling dbCommand.Connection.Close and dbCommand.Connection.Dispose() I though he was asking if that was needed since he was already wrapping the command in a using block.

If he was asking if he still needs to call something like db.Close and db.Dispose then you are 100% correct.  I just did not think that is what his question was.

Comment: "if I already use using to wrap my DBCommand, do I have to close the *underneath connection* explicitly" That seems pretty clearly worded.

Comment: And his comment in the code, again, refers to explicitly closing the connection (which he's doing).

Comment: And, again, calling dbCommand.Dispose() (which is what the using block does), does **not** call dbCommand.Connection.Dispose().